# Dal2 Cacheable attribute - setting cache time to zero

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have some records in a DNN database used by a custom module, it is important that they are never cached, but rather the fresh data is returned each time it is requested.

Is it better to set a cachable attribut to zero, or remove the cachable attribute all together (or is this the same)?

```
Imports DotNetNuke.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Namespace Components
  <TableName("vw_MyView")>
  <PrimaryKey("PrimaryKey", AutoIncrement:=True)>
  <Cacheable("vw_MyView", CacheItemPriority.Default, 0)>
  <Scope("PortalID")>
  Public Class vw_KrisisShifts_Expired_ShiftTrade_Details
       ....
  End Class
End Namespace
```

OR

```
  <TableName("vw_MyView")>
  <PrimaryKey("PrimaryKey", AutoIncrement:=True)>
  <Scope("PortalID")>
  Public Class vw_KrisisShifts_Expired_ShiftTrade_Details
       ....
  End Class
```